# C++ - How to clear variables after a while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, variables

I have not found a reason why this happen nor a way to avoid it.

In C++, I am trying to declare a temporary variable that works only inside every while loop, and supposed to be destroyed after this ends.

I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    while (foo) {
        float SampleVariable;
        ...
        std::cout << SampleVariable << std::endl;
        ...
        SampleVariable = 20;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the first loop, the `SampleVariable` output value is `5.8825e-39`; but in the second loop and the following, the output value of `SampleVariable` is `20`.

Comment: Undefined behaviour

Comment: You are supposed to give it a value at the *beginning* of the loop, not the end. Anyway, even if the variable is destroyed at the end of the loop, the compiler will likely use the same bytes for the variable each time (because that is the easiest way).

Comment: You deal with an uninitialized variable inside of the while loop's body, and what you see is merely _undefined behavior_. I'd go to my wardrobe to inspect if my cat beared kittens. Ah wait, I have no cat :-P ...

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: _"it was just a harmless question"_ Well, there are several issues with it. Let's start with the missing [MCVE]. You can't reproduce that behavior certainly with any other standard conformant compiler.

Comment: @Davdriver You probably missed the goal of this site.

Comment: We want a mix of killer and introductory questions. To get both, we need to put up with some amount of repetition from those who don't realize they've asked a bog-standard question because 1) they haven't asked it before, 10) they don't know the keywords to look for it, and 11) if they knew the keywords they'd also know the answer and not ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that in computing, when ever something is destroyed, it is not set to 0 or some magic value. It is simply set to be overwritten when the next process comes.

In your loop, you didn't initialize `SampleVariable` and it just took what ever value was there before. In the first iteration it's whatever was there before. In the next few iterations, it's what `SampleVariable` was in the past iteration because by chance (not really), your float got assigned to the same location in memory.

Initialize your variable like

```
float SampleVariable = 0.f;
```

and the your `std::cout` will print 0 everytime.

Comment: /OT Oh, a _blinkenlight_ clone ;-)

Comment: Nothing here hets **deleted**. At the end of the block `SampleVariable` Gets **destroyed**.

Comment: Noted, edited..

Answer (score 1):

> In the first loop, the `SampleVariable` output value is `5.8825e-39`, as it should be

Actually **any** output is "what it should be" because you're invoking UB by accessing objects with indeternimate value. There's no way to "clear" a variable. At every loop its state is resetted to "indeterminate", which means that any value is applicable. You should give up trying to "reset" it.